# Can't send data from objective-c via POST

Tags: objective-c, django, post, nsurlconnection

i'm developing an app for iPhone and I'm stuck in one call, I have to send data via POST, the django web programmer tells me the app has to receive

```
param_one = request.POST['param_one']
param_two = request.POST['param_two']
```

but I cannot make it to send any data...

I'm learning objective-c, so please, could you tell me how to do it with an example?

PS: all the other calls that doesn't send any data, or pass data through url (GET method) works fine, so I'm making the connection correctly

Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:@"somename" forKey:@"user"];
NSString *jsonString = [dict JSONRepresentation];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *  request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://web.com/custom/url/call/"]];
[request setValue:jsonString forHTTPHeaderField:@"json"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:csrf forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRFToken"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
senddata = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add:

```
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Then the server will know that what you're sending is UTF-8 encoded JSON and it will be able to parse it appropriately. Otherwise it just gets a formless blob of data.

Unless it's for debugging purposes, it's very odd that you put the JSON string into both the header and the body.

Comment: Thanks Tommy, something odd keeps happening to me, maybe you know why. If I add a '/' at the end of the url, I get this message: <p>Reason given for failure:</p>
    <pre>
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
    </pre>
You know why?

Comment: I'm insufficiently knowledgeable to be completely confident of how Django handles its cross site request forgery (CSRF) token; if your server guy is expecting it to work via cookies, make sure you've made a call like `[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];` and the iOS HTTP request mechanisms will catch, store and subsequently attach relevant cookies for you.

Comment: @Sascuash Django's CSRF token is explained in depth in the Django docs. Basially, you should do what Tommy suggests, and look for the CSRF token in a cookie and return it in your request. Django's Csrf Middleware looks for this token on any unsafe HTTP requests, of which POST is one.